# How close to aperture is Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction formula valid, and how does light diffract prior this regime?

Tags: diffraction, optics

In the scalar diffractive optics theory that I have seen (e.g., as presented in Goodman - "Introduction to Fourier Optics"), the main equation for diffraction by an aperture is the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction formula:

$$U(x,y)=-\frac{i}{\lambda}\int_{\Sigma}U(\xi,\eta)\frac{\exp(ikr)}{r}\cos(\theta)ds,$$

with $r$ is the distance from the surface point $(\xi,\eta,0)$ to the observation point $(x,y,z)$, and $\cos(\theta)$ is the obliquity factor. (Some common alternatives that use a different obliquity factor and give nearly identical results can be used as well.) Taking the paraxial approximation and going further from the aperture, the formula limits to the Fresnel formula, and then the Fraunhofer formula.

The derivation of RS and its nearly identical alternatives already assumes that the observed field is many wavelengths from the aperture. I have three questions:

1. Is there a rough rule for how far from the aperture a field must be for RS to be a good description of the propagating field?
2. Are there good ways to think about diffraction in the extreme near field, prior to where the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld equation becomes accurate?
3. Are there names for these regimes? I.e., the Fresnel regime is called the near field - is there a name for the RS regime prior to the near field, and for the regime behind an aperture but prior to the RS regime?

Thanks for any help.